# Ошибка [HY010] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Function sequence error (0) (SQLFetch) при записи в файл

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy

Делаю выгрузку из БД (диалект Microsoft SQL Server).
Программа запускается на сервере под Линуксом, ресурс оперативной памяти ограничен.
Поэтому использую функцию pd.read_sql_query() c параметром **chunksize**.

#### Порядок действий:

1. Подключиться к БД и получить объект Iterator[DataFrame]

   ```py
   @time_of_function
   def _get_chunks_iterator(url_object: URL, query: text, chunk_size: int = 10000) -> Iterator[DataFrame]:

       engine = create_engine(url_object)
       with engine.connect() as cnxn:
           return read_sql_query(query, cnxn, chunksize=chunk_size)
   ```
2. Из полученного итератора перебрать все датафреймы и записать в файл 
   одной из фукнций (в зависимости от переданного формата).

- Excel:

  ```py
  @time_of_function
  def _make_xl_out_of_iterator(chunks_iterator: Iterator[DataFrame], path: str) -> None:
      with ExcelWriter(path, engine="openpyxl", mode='w') as writer:
          chunk = next(chunks_iterator)
          chunk.to_excel(writer, index=False, engine='openpyxl')
          # первую строку займут заголовки
          # строка len(chunk) + 1 будет последней непустой
          # строка len(chunk) + 2 будет первой свободной для записи
          first_empty_line = chunk.shape[0] + 2

      for chunk in chunks_iterator:
          update_spreadsheet(path, chunk, starcol=1, startrow=first_empty_line)
          first_empty_line += chunk.shape[0]
  ```
- CSV:

  ```py
  @time_of_function
  def _make_csv_out_of_iterator(chunks_iterator: Iterator[DataFrame], path: str) -> None:
      with open(path, 'w') as f_out:
          next(chunks_iterator).to_csv(f_out, index=False)  # запись первого чанка с названием столбцов

          for chunk in chunks_iterator:
              chunk.to_csv(f_out, index=False, header=False)  # пропускаем запись названий столбцов
  ```

#### Где возникает ошибка?

Функция _get_chunks_iterator() отрабатывает без вызова ошибок.
Но при вызове одной одной из функций пункта (2) возникает ошибка с таким трейсбеком:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\U_M1GT7\SHELTER\AAProjects\ossktb-rcsite-reporter-api\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\cursor.py", line 1138, in fetchmany
    l = dbapi_cursor.fetchmany(size)
pyodbc.Error: ('HY010', '[HY010] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Function sequence error (0) (SQLFetch)')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\U_M1GT7\SHELTER\AAProjects\ossktb-rcsite-reporter-api\auxiliary\df_itarator_to_excel.py", line 324, in <module>
    prepare_report_file(sql3, absolute_path=CSV_REPORT_PATH, file_format='csv')
  File "C:\Users\U_M1GT7\SHELTER\AAProjects\ossktb-rcsite-reporter-api\auxiliary\df_itarator_to_excel.py", line 28, in wrapper
    res = function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\U_M1GT7\SHELTER\AAProjects\ossktb-rcsite-reporter-api\auxiliary\df_itarator_to_excel.py", line 188, in prepare_report_file
    _make_csv_out_of_iterator(chunks_iter, absolute_path)
  File "C:\Users\U_M1GT7\SHELTER\AAProjects\ossktb-rcsite-reporter-api\auxiliary\df_itarator_to_excel.py", line 28, in wrapper
    res = function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\U_M1GT7\SHELTER\AAProjects\ossktb-rcsite-reporter-api\auxiliary\df_itarator_to_excel.py", line 173, in _make_csv_out_of_iterator
    next(chunks_iterator).to_csv(f_out, index=False)  # запись первого чанка с названием столбцов
  File "C:\Users\U_M1GT7\SHELTER\AAProjects\ossktb-rcsite-reporter-api\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1480, in _query_iterator
    data = result.fetchmany(chunksize)
  File "C:\Users\U_M1GT7\SHELTER\AAProjects\ossktb-rcsite-reporter-api\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\result.py", line 1346, in fetchmany
    return self._manyrow_getter(self, size)
  File "C:\Users\U_M1GT7\SHELTER\AAProjects\ossktb-rcsite-reporter-api\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\result.py", line 697, in manyrows
    rows: List[_InterimRowType[Any]] = self._fetchmany_impl(num)
  File "C:\Users\U_M1GT7\SHELTER\AAProjects\ossktb-rcsite-reporter-api\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\cursor.py", line 2107, in _fetchmany_impl
    return self.cursor_strategy.fetchmany(self, self.cursor, size)
  File "C:\Users\U_M1GT7\SHELTER\AAProjects\ossktb-rcsite-reporter-api\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\cursor.py", line 1144, in fetchmany
    self.handle_exception(result, dbapi_cursor, e)
  File "C:\Users\U_M1GT7\SHELTER\AAProjects\ossktb-rcsite-reporter-api\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\cursor.py", line 1097, in handle_exception
    result.connection._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "C:\Users\U_M1GT7\SHELTER\AAProjects\ossktb-rcsite-reporter-api\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2326, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    raise sqlalchemy_exception.with_traceback(exc_info[2]) from e
  File "C:\Users\U_M1GT7\SHELTER\AAProjects\ossktb-rcsite-reporter-api\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\cursor.py", line 1138, in fetchmany
    l = dbapi_cursor.fetchmany(size)
sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('HY010', '[HY010] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Function sequence error (0) (SQLFetch)')
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/dbapi)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Всё ломается, когда пытаюсь применить функцию next() к полученному итератору.

#### Вопросы:

1. Корректно ли я получаю данные из БД, разбивая на чанки?
2. Что может приводить к ошибке **Function sequence error (0) (SQLFetch)**?
3. Как её исправить?

#### P.S.

Я нашёл такое решение: https://issuehint.com/issue/groveco/django-sql-explorer/423 
Но я не понимаю, подходит ли оно мне и как его использовать (где менять эти значения на False)
[image: Ответ другого пользователя]

Прошу подсказать, спасибо за любую помощь.

Comment: Интересный у вас, конечно, подход, на первый вгляд всё хорошо должно быть. Но зачем спускаться до sql_alchemy, если можно использовать [`pd.read_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html#pandas-read-sql) где всё за вас уже изобретено. Да, он не идеален, поэтому иногда приходится что-то на чистом sql выдумывать, но в нём тоже есть чанки, почему бы не попробовать?

Comment: Почитал про pd.read_sql(). По сути, это обёртка pd.read_sql_query().
Попробовал заменить в коде, ошибка осталась

Comment: Думаю стоит смотреть что на стороне SQL происходит. Что за сервер, какая версия? Можно нативно погонять запросы? Sqlachemy должна выводить в консоль запрос на котором всё падает.

Comment: По запросу `SELECT @@version` выводит это:
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU17) (KB5001092) - 13.0.5888.11 (X64)   Mar 19 2021 19:41:38   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: )
Сами запросы, которые я использую в программе выполняются на сервере без ошибок.

sqlachemy в консоль сапрос сам не выводит.

Comment: Как выяснить, где возникает ошибка? Какие хоть способы есть?
Может, проблема действительно в автокоммитах, как пишут здесь https://issuehint.com/issue/groveco/django-sql-explorer/423?

Comment: Что-то мне казалось, что он по дефолту выводит запросы в Jupyter, по крайней мере когда в одном вопросе игрались с автоматизацией создания таблиц было так. [Можно включить](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2950685/8489602), а также смотреть [логи](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/sql-server-audit-database-engine?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver16) на самом сервере. Возможно из профилирования что-то полезное можно будет узнать.

Comment: Про коммиты, не знаю, не думаю, не уверен. Вы же читаете из базы, а не пишите в неё. Но не исключено, что с курсорами что-то не так.

Comment: Добавил логирование. Теперь в консоли вижу это `
...
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:SELECT TOP 100 * FROM LM1.dbo.vftSimpleRequest_listALL WITH (NOLOCK)
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:[generated in 0.00021s] ()
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:ROLLBACK
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\U_M1GT7\SHELTER\AAProjects\ossktb-rcsite-reporter-api\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\cursor.py", line 1138, in fetchmany
    l = dbapi_cursor.fetchmany(size)
pyodbc.Error: ('HY010', '[HY010] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Function sequence error (0) (SQLFetch)')
 ...
`

Comment: нет возможности здесь полный текст логов вставить, но суть в том, что проблем явных не наблюдаю

Comment: но последние три строчки логов такие:
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:BEGIN (implicit)
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:SELECT TOP 100 * FROM LM1.dbo.vftSimpleRequest_listALL WITH (NOLOCK)
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:[generated in 0.00021s] ()
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:ROLLBACK

откуда ROLLBACK?

Comment: Логи можно добавить в вопрос отредактировав его. Но, как я и предполагал про курсор. На чанки можно разбить делая запросы по PK, где в цикле перебирать чанки. Очень низкоуровнево, но как минимум это должно быть решением проблемы. Что-то в стандартных механизмах не работает, и пока сам не пощупаешь, сложно сказать что.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема оказалась простой. Её корни в этой функции:

```
@time_of_function
def _get_chunks_iterator(url_object: URL, query: text, chunk_size: int = 10000) -> Iterator[DataFrame]:

    engine = create_engine(url_object)
    with engine.connect() as cnxn:
        return read_sql_query(query, cnxn, chunksize=chunk_size)
```

Нарушена логика работы с БД. Я открыл соединение **cnxn** внутри конструкции **with**.
Пока существует это соединение, я могу итерироваться по результату, который возвращает БД.
Но, как только функция **_get_chunks_iterator()** завершается и возвращает ссылку на итератор, эта ссылка становится бесполезной, так как конструкция **with** всё за собой подчищает (закрывает созданный процесс или что-то подобное, тут не до конца разобрался).
Решение: получить итератор от функции **read_sql_query**(..., chunksize=chunk_size) и обработать его внутри конструкции **with**.

В результате написал такую функцию:

```
def prepare_report_file(server: str,
                        sql_query: str,
                        absolute_path: str,
                        file_format: str = 'xlsx',
                        ) -> None:
    """
    Создать и сохранить файл в примонтированную папку.

    :param server: название сервера с БД
    :param sql_query: текст запроса, полученный из формы на сайте
    :param absolute_path: полный адрес, по которому должен быть сохранен файл
    :param file_format: формат файла ('xlsx' или 'csv')
    :return: None
    """
    sql_query = text(sql_query)

    conn_url = prepare_connection_url(host=server)
    engine = create_engine(conn_url)

    with engine.connect().execution_options(stream_results=True) as conn:
        chunks_iter = pd.read_sql(sql_query, conn, chunksize=OPTIMAL_CHUNKSIZE)

        if file_format == 'xlsx':
            _make_xl_out_of_iterator(chunks_iter, absolute_path)
        elif file_format == 'csv':
            _make_csv_out_of_iterator(chunks_iter, absolute_path)
```

С ней такой ошики больше не возникает.